# listfragment simple example

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Hello i want to get simple list fragment example i have searched out but could not get it so  please can any body help me

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

i have searched out but mostly in import android.app.*;

so any body help me to find out example so it is not working on my android 2.2

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.displayList, listFragment, "List_Fragment");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
```

i m getting error over getFragmentmanger

this example must be in below android 3.0

Comment: did you put android support-V4 library in your project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using the support library, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` (the method name in the support library) instead of `getFragmentManager` (which is the method name in post 3.0).

Answer (score 16):

Another very simple list fragment example:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/a-listfragment-application-in-android/

Comment: For pre-Honeycomb versions, please refer [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/a-listfragment-application-with-backward-compatibility-in-android/) article

Answer (score -6):

Here you have a simple example of fragment, easily adaptable for Listfragment

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1160

Comment: This is an example of a ListView inside an Activity, not of ListFragment.